# Censorship of latest state in state channel

Tags: proof-of-stake, timelock, state-channels

Does shifting to Proof-of-Stake prevent censoring of latest channel state in ethereum-based state channels? As far as my understanding, censoring of transaction will persist as the miners can still be bribed to mine stale state and ignore the latest state. Is it correct? Can there be timelocke